# lighttpd, php, SoapClient not found

Tags: php, soap, lighttpd

I am trying to install this on a switch using buildroot, I added php and lighttpd to the build. I start the server and the webpage gives this error:

```
Fatal error Class 'SoapClient' not found
```

I went to php.ini and uncommented `extension=php_soap.dll`    (changed .dll to .so as I'm on linux, this right?) I also stuck in `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1`

The error is still there, any ideas?

Do I have to enable some option so that soap is supported? as I can't find php_soap anywhere

Comment: is the .so file on the os in the first place?  also have you checked php docs http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php make sure you've got all the soap options there set.

Comment: I can't find a .so file no. I have --enable-soap in my ./configure in buildroot, however I checked phpinfo on the switch and there is no mention of soap at all

Comment: Did yo ucustom compile php then ? if you can't find the .so file then thats why its not showing up in phpinfo cos php does not have the library it requires to load the soapclient module.  Sort out the missing library and it should work.

Comment: When I was building php the makefile was being overwritten. I fixed that now and it all works cheers :) The so file is nowhere still but that doesnt seem to matter.

Comment: `locate php_soap.so` should be in something like /usr/lib/ or something

Comment: Doesnt exist on teh switch --enable-soap was all I needed, didnt touch php.ini in the end